# BlackBerry Android Push Message Server

Tags: android, push-notification, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I'mm having problems when trying to push notifications for my Z10. The device successfully registers for push notifications and I receive the BlackBerry generated registration ID as described in ["Creating Push-Enabled Android Apps"](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html).

I am having problems though when trying to send notifications to that server.

For regular Android I was using a  [GCM server library](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-server/).
I had to modify it so that the message is sent to BlackBerry servers i.e. https://cpXXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com where XXX is my CPID (Content Provider ID).

The problem is that I receive a 404 in return and don't know what's causing that... Any ideas? the same message gets sent to a regular Android device successfully...

Alternatively, did anyone succeed in sending push messages to your device and if so, could you share how the request should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make a push request. You have to push it to BlackBerry servers. I used BB SDK available [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/?CPID=PUSHAPI00). The URL you have to use should look like this:

```
https://cpXXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest
```

sample code:

```
IdGenerator idGenerator = new IdGeneratorImpl();

        List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        //populate message with key-value pairs
        String data = message.toString();
        //populate addresses with device PINs

        PushMessageControl pushMessageControl = new PushMessageControl(PPGType.PUBLIC_PUSH, idGenerator, "[ YOUR BlackBerryAppId]", addresses);

        Content content = new TextContent(data, "UTF-8");

        PapService papService = new PapServiceImpl();

        PushSDKProperties properties = new PushSDKPropertiesImpl();
        properties.setPublicPpgAddress("[YOUR BLACKBERRY PPG ADDRESS]");
        properties.setParserSpecialCharacters(BLACKBERRY_PARSER_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS);
        properties.setHttpIsPersistent(false);
        properties.setHttpConnectionTimeout(BLACKBERRY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        properties.setDtdDeclarationPublic(BLACKBERRY_DTD_DECLARATION_PUBLIC);
        properties.setHttpReadTimeout(BLACKBERRY_READ_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClientImpl client = new HttpClientImpl();
        client.setPushSDKProperties(properties);
        papService.setHttpClient(client);
        papService.setPushSDKProperties(properties);

        PushResponse response = papService.push("[ YOUR BlackBerryAppId]", "[ YOUR BlackBerryPassword]", "[ YOUR BlackBerryAppId]", pushMessageControl, content);
```

where

```
private static final int BLACKBERRY_READ_TIMEOUT = 120000;

private static final int BLACKBERRY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 60000;

private static final char[] BLACKBERRY_PARSER_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = new char[] {'&', '"', ':', '<'};

private static final String BLACKBERRY_DTD_DECLARATION_PUBLIC = "<!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC \"-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN\" \"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/pap_2.1.dtd\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

For your request there are many things you have add:

1. you have to create request to this URL `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.
2. you have to add to the header of your request the Server API Key.
3. and also you have to add to the header of your request Sender ID which are both 2 and 3 provided to you by Google API console.
4. Finally, this is the code that I used to push notification for my 5000 and more users:

Note: it has been developed by ASP.Net and VB.Net but all must applied the same principles:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: key=AIzaSyA47-XMaePL1mmI0P1yQ9V4sntMVn9q-1o")
request.Headers.Add("Sender: id=648406549877")
Dim collapsKey = Guid.NewGuid.ToString("n")
Dim postdata As String = "{""registration_ids"":" + ids(j) + ",""data"":{""message"":""" + TextBox1.Text + """,}" + ",""collapse_key"":""" + collapsKey + """,}"
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
Dim resposne As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
Dim dataresponse As Stream = resposne.GetResponseStream
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataresponse)
Dim sResponseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd
reader.Close()
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I think what you described is how sending push notifications to Android devices works and GCMs Java server library does exactly the same. My problem is how to do this for BlackBerry devices (on which you can deploy your APK files)